# Deploy React + asp.net core to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, iis, .net-core

I'm using the React template in Visual Studio, and I'm now trying to deploy it to IIS.

My IIS looks like this:

[image]

The application pool look like this:

[image]

After I've published the files to IIS, and I go to the url, nothing happens. When I hit Manage Application->Browse in IIS, nothing happens.

I can use the application if I go to the ClienApp folder in the project, open cmd, and writes `dotnet ICON.Breif.UI.dll`, then the projects starts.

So I guess it has something to do with the node server when I publish to IIS?

Comment: Npm has nothing to do here. Basically npm is only used to compile client side reactjs

Comment: @Sameer so what is happening? Because if i run dotnet ICOM.Breif.UI.dll in cmd, and goes to localhost:5124, it works.

Comment: have you installed .net core hosting bundle on your machine?

Comment: @Sameer yes, im hosting other .net core projects.

Comment: Could you please tell us your IIS version? Which asp.net core application version you have used now?  Which deploy-mode you have selected? Framework-Dependent or Self-contained?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what did the trick for me, got a hint from [HERE](https://github.com/aspnet/templating/issues/555) (apparently this is a known issue). Not the most flexible solution, but it works

1. In VS, open package.json (in your React App folder - if you used VS template to create the project - it will be called ClientApp)
2. On top of the file, under "name", "version" or "private" add new item, called "homepage"
3. for "homepage" value, put "/[YOUR_APP_NAME_IN_IIS]" (forward slash) followed by name of your application exactly as you have it in IIS.
4. Deploy

[image: ReactRedux with .Net Core in IIS not working]

It should render now:

[image: working IIS react-redux .net core vs template]

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of asp.net core your using, currently I don't which version, if your using asp.net core version 3.0 then:
please follow the link:
Link:https://dotnetdetail.net/deploy-react-and-asp-net-core-3-0-application-to-iis/